# Unable to call a function to retrieve a "value" parameter and replace characters in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is some code that another developer repeated. 
I want to put that in a function and then call it but now I am a bit confuse.

This is the code I have:

```
if(true) {
    $(this).attr('id', function (i, val) {
       return val.replace('Less', 'More');
    }).attr('data-bactmln', function (i, val) {
       return val.replace('Less', 'More')
    });
} else {
    $(this).attr('id', function (i, val) {
       return val.replace('More', 'Less');
    }).attr('data-bactmln', function (i, val) {
       return val.replace('More', 'Less')
    });
}
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
var toggleTealiumId = function(p1, p2) {
    return val.replace(p1, p2);
};

if(true) {
   $(this).attr('id', toggleTealiumId('More', 'Less'));
} else {
   $(this).attr('data-bactmln', toggleTealiumId('Less', 'More'));
}
```

That `val` is the `value` of the string as in the first lines of code, but for now I am getting `undefined`.

So how can I stop `val` from being `undefined` and do it in a proper way?

Any suggestions?

Comment: `if(true) { ... }`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis it's pseudo code in that part only. `if(true) {//do this}` it's implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write it that way:

```
function toggleTealiumId(p1, p2) {
  return function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(p1, p2);
  }
}
```

The call `toggleTealiumId('More', 'Less')` will return a function where `p1` and `p2` are *bound* to `'More'` and `'Less'` (Take a look at [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102)
 for more details), this function then can be passed as argument to `attr`.

Comment: I typically like to name these functions that return handlers something that implies that it returns a function. For example, `createToggleTealiumCallback`